# How the change the scss variable based on media queries

Tags: html, css, sass

I am working on a `scss` based web page and encountered an issue. I have the following `scss` function to convert my font `px` units to `rem`.

```
@function rem($size) {
 $remSize: $size / $base-size;
 @return #{$remSize}rem;
}
```

In the above function the `$base-size` is static and it remains `16` but I want to change the `base-size` to `12` when I target the mobile devices so that it reduces the redundancy of changing the `font-size` throughout the project. Is there any approach I can make the `$base-size` dynamic so that the value changes based on the screen resolution. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't possible, so far as I am aware. The `$base-size` variable gets filled once and the media query happens on the client-side.

You can try to write a new function for each media-query with a new base-size variable and value.

Variables:

```
$base-size: 16px;
$base-size-small: 12x;
```

> Edit: For the same reason, the function below doesn't work.

Functions:

```
@function rem($size) {
 $remSize: $size / $base-size;
 @return #{$remSize}rem;
}

@media only screen and (max-width : 768px) {
  @function rem($size) {
   $remSize: $size / $base-size-small;
   @return #{$remSize}rem;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are probably many workarounds for this, depending on how much complexity you are okay working with.

Without knowing the details of your project, this might be one solution - if I understand correctly how you are using your function:

```
$base-size: 16px;

@function rem($size, $screen: desktop) {
    $remSize: null;

    @if ($screen == desktop) {
        $remSize: ($size / $base-size) * 16/16;
    }
    @if ($screen == mobile) {
        $remSize: ($size / $base-size) * 12/16;
    }
    @else {
        $remSize: $size / $base-size;
    }

    @return #{$remSize}rem;
}

.some-text {
    font-size: rem(24px); /* = 1.5rem */
}

@media (max-width: 480px) {
    .some-text {
        font-size: rem(24px, mobile); /* = 1.125rem */
    }
}
```

By adding a `$screen` argument to your `rem()` function, you can switch base size between desktop and mobile without changing the static variable.

This example defaults to `desktop` and uses `max-with` in the media query, but could just as well default to `mobile` and you could differenciate with `min-width`.

Comment: To be more specific I dont want any extra argument to be passed in my function instead my function should be clever to return the base-size based on the media screen.

Comment: For instance my body base font size is `16px` which is based on which the other font size works on rem. If I change my body base font size to be 12 the rest has the change its rem value based on it..

Answer (score 0):

I can't find this solution.

Because media query works in runtime stage. Sass works in compile stage.

So, I set html's font size to 62.5%(10px)

Then used rem slightly easy.

```
html {
     font-size: 62.5%; // 10px;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 769px) { 
    html { 
        font-size: 125%; // 20px;
    }
}

.example {
   padding: 0.5rem; // 5px => 10px  
}
```